# ImportError when using heroku for my django web

Tags: django, selenium, heroku, importerror

I checked django is installed properly and in my 'requirements.txt' I wrote 'Django==3.2.3'. However, I cannot use this code:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

So I checked this code:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

and found out it worked properly. I know that there are existing questions and read many of them, but I think I have tried everything I could do. I would be really grateful if someone can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question isn't clear tbh.

install all the dependencies by using the `pip freeze` command and try to run your heroku commands in the heroku bash available in your heroku dashboard

to run the commands on your heroku machine from your CMD, then command is

`heroku run bash --app your_app_name`

then you can run whatever command you want.

but I am not sure what is the exact problem you are having.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention the error was about "ImportError:Couldn't import Django". I have checked out all libraries I needed via 'pip freeze' command and django was installed properly. Sorry for the unclear sentences!

Comment: did you try running migrations from your heroku dashboard?

Comment: No, I only used heroku CLI.